# HTML input button changing content

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm trying to change the contents of an input tag using a JS function but nothing I tried seems to work. Here's what I tried:

```js
function go (){
document.getElementById("input").innerHTML.value =  5;
};
```

```html
<body>

<input type="number" id="input">

<button onclick="go()">go</button>

</body>
```

Would really appreaciate it if someone show me how this is done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use `document.getElementById("input").value`

```js
function go (){
   document.getElementById("input").value =  5;
};
```

```html
<body>

<input type="number" id="input">

<button onclick="go()">go</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to change the innerHTML, just the value of the input element (which is an attribute). So this should work. I changed to a string because that's what attributes usually are, but it shouldn't matter.

```
document.getElementById("input").value =  "5";
```